# TestRPC and persistence of data

Tags: testrpc, nodejs

I am using a smart contract on the TestRPC net.
In order to deploy my contract for the first time I write this in the node cmd:

```
>Web3 = require('web3') 
> web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")); 
> code = fs.readFileSync('store.sol').toString() 
> solc = require('solc') 
> compiledCode = solc.compile(code) 
> abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts[':SimpleStorage'].interface) 
> SimpleStorage = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition) 
> byteCode = compiledCode.contracts[':SimpleStorage'].bytecode 
> deployedContract = SimpleStorage.new(['Rama'],{data: byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000}) 
> deployedContract.address
```

In this way I get contract abi and address.
The only problem is that evry time I restart TestRPC I have to repeat the above commands...There is a way to avoid this or,at least,make this automatical?

(this is the js script I actually use to use the contract:

```
var net = require('net'); 

var HOST = '127.0.0.1'; 
var PORT = 10001; 
var Web3 = require('web3'); 
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('localhost:8545')); 



net.createServer(function(sock) { 



sock.setEncoding('utf8'); 
sock.on('data', function(data) { 
console.log('__________'); 

console.log(data); 

console.log('__________'); 
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")); 
abi = JSON.parse('[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"string"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]'); 
SimpleStorage = web3.eth.contract(abi); 

contractInstance = SimpleStorage.at('0x08cf472e9192d3c48e03f501472c8aecb9350c16'); 

contractInstance.set(data, {from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000}); 

 x=contractInstance.get({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000}); 
 console.log(x); 

}); 



// Aggiungiamo l'event handler 'close' per questa istanza di socket 
sock.on('close', function(data) { 


}); 



}).listen(PORT, HOST); 

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

EDIT
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testrpc accept a parameter [`--db`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc#command-line)

> `--db`: Specify a path to a directory to save the chain database. If a database already exists, the TestRPC will initialize that chain instead of creating a new one.

Comment: So i write : "Testrpc -- db/home/ " and it creates a db in that directory??

Comment: You probably also want `-d` to deterministicaly generate accounts, so everytime you have the same accounts generates. Create a directory mydatadir and then execute `testrpc --db mydatadir -d`. But remember testrpc is mostly for quick tests if you want a more complex development you probably want to setup a private testnet or use a public testnet like Ropsten.

Comment: For what I have to do now,I just need I can use my contract without repeating  evry commands evry time

Comment: I got an error,look at the post

Comment: The error say that some other process is using port 8545, likely you have another instance testrpc or geth running.